# PHP Fake Subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a project that allows to open free lots of websites. They have to run on subdomains that user whatever wants. I cannot create a new real subdomains for all users and I cannot copy all the files to new subdomain when new sites are creating. It has to refer my main website. So, I want to have a system like this:

**For "example" subdomain:**

```
example.domain.com -> domain.com/index.php?subdomain=example
example.domain.com/foo.php -> domain.com/foo.php?subdomain=example
example.domain.com/bar.php?foo=bar -> domain.com/bar.php?subdomain=example&foo=bar
```

**For "new" subdomain:**

```
new.domain.com -> domain.com/index.php?subdomain=example
new.domain.com/foo.php -> domain.com/foo.php?subdomain=example
new.domain.com/bar.php?foo=bar -> domain.com/bar.php?subdomain=example&foo=bar
```

etc...

How can I do this?

*Thanks!*

Comment: This _might_ be possible depending on the configuration of your http server and the dns entries for your domain. In both cases you need wildcard entries. Otherwise there is nothing php or the http server can do, since the requests won't reach your system.

Comment: _If_ that is the case, then I don't see much issue here. The biggest question probably is how to handle all those domain names in a dynamic manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com(.*) /index.php?subdomain=$1
```

But you don't need `RewriteEngine` for your task... just setup server so it would host `*.domain.com` and in your PHP scripts use something like that:

```
    <?php
       $subdomain = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))); // will for example return "example" for "example.domain.com"
       if($subdomain == 'example'){
          do_something();
       }else if($subdomain == 'new'){
          do_something_new();
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Why not simply capture the host name in the condition and use it in the rule?

Comment: Check [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) under `Virtual User Hosts`

Comment: I am just answering the question :-) Question was about how to do that with `.htaccess` :-)

Comment: I asked why not to simply capture that part of the hostname in the condition. But as said: ok...

Comment: Because you can't use the `host` later... `RewriteRule` applies only to part after the host... that trick does the job, to move it from URL to URI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137217/discussion-between-arkascha-and-flash-thunder).

Comment: It does not work unfortunately... There was an error like this: "Server not found" @FlashThunder Also, it can be everything, if it is working, there is no problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: you are getting server not found becase you have to setup wildcard virtualhost in http server configuration for that domain ... `*.domain.com` as well as wildcard `A` or `CNAME` in `DNS` configuration for that domain.

Comment: It totally doesn't have to be `htaccess` ... you can get the origin domain from `PHP` via `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and put condition directly into `PHP` script.

Comment: As I sad before, I have lots of websites, if i don't use the .htaccess, how can i show the sites, when user open the subdomain.domain.com, i have to show domain.com and i have to detect the subdomain name, because, i will get the data from mysql with subdomain name and i will print the data... @FlashThunder